# Why is my Project Euler problem #1 code returning the wrong result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem 1 Project Euler, which asks you to find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000, so 3 + 5 + 6 + 9, etc.

The correct answer is 233168 but my code is returning 266333.

I'm not looking to use a different method, I'm wondering why this code isn't working as is, from the debugging that I did it looks as everything that I am expecting to see is there.

```
numArray = []
a = 0
b = 0
total = 0
totala = 0
totalb = 0
#numArray a and b were for testing purposes to make sure array was correct length
numArraya = []
numArrayb = []
while a < 1000:
    numArray.append(a)
    numArraya.append(a)
    a += 3
#expecting to get 334, returns 334
#print (len(numArraya))
while b < 1000:
    numArray.append(b)
    numArrayb.append(b)
    b += 5
#expecting 200, returns 200
#print (len(numArrayb))

#for numa in numArraya:
#    totala += numa
#print (totala)

#for numb in numArrayb:
#    totalb += numb
#print (totalb)

for num in numArray:
    total += num
print (total)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well your edit certainly clarifies what the code is expected to do. I'm just not sure how this is helpful to anyone else but the OP. Might as well be simply *How to solve project Euler problem 1?*

Comment: @Tomerikoo: the majority of this class of questions are very specific to the code shown. The question *How to solve project Euler problem 1* without such code would be closable as too broad (needs more focus). This one is not that question, *because it has a specific attempt included*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution includes numbers that are multiples of both 3 and 5, *twice*. You are adding 15, 30, 45, etc. twice to the final sum:

```
>>> 266333 - 233168  # the difference between the correct answer and yours
33165
>>> sum(range(0, 1000, 15)) # is the same as the sum of all multiples of 15 < 1000
33165
```

Your solution can be fixed by testing if `b` is already present in `numArray`:

```
while b < 1000:
    if b not in numArray:
        numArray.append(b)
        numArrayb.append(b)
    b += 5
```

The simpler solution is to just loop from 0 to 999 and test each number with the `%` modulus operator; if the outcome is 0, the left-hand side number is divisible by the right-hand side argument. Together with the `sum()` built-in function and a generator expression, that becomes:

```
sum(x for x in range(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

Your approach, if cast as a set problem, is fine too:

```
sum(set(range(0, 1000, 3)).union(range(0, 1000, 5)))
```

Both approaches still loop and thus will take more time as the numbers grow. There is however a mathematical solution that takes constant time.

Note that your 'bug' hints at a possible path; if the sum of all multiples of 3 and multiples of 5 below 1000 was off by the sum of all multiples of (3 times 5 == 15) below 1000, then if you have a simple formula to calculate the sum of any multiple of x below n then you can calculate the solution to this problem by adding the sums for 3 and 5 and subtracting the sum for 15.

In other words, if `f(x, n)` calculates the total sum of all multiples of `x` below `n`, then the solution to Euler #1 is equal to `f(3, 1000) + f(5, 1000) - f(3 * 5, 1000)`.

In this case, `f` is the [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) of the divisor of n over x, and x:

```
def f(x, n):
    """sum of all multiples of x below n"""
    divisor = (n - 1) // x
    return (divisor * x * (divisor + 1)) // 2
```

giving you a straight, linear time outcome:

```
>>> def f(x, n):
...     """sum of all multiples of x below n"""
...     divisor = (n - 1) // x
...     return (divisor * x * (divisor + 1)) // 2
... 
>>> f(3, 1000) + f(5, 1000) - f(3 * 5, 1000)
233168
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I feel silly, I was testing it with the example of 10 and getting the result that they got and got very confused when it got to higher numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one variable to store the summed up value, starting at 0:

```
store: int = 0

for i in range(3, 1000):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        store += i
    elif i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        store += i

print(store)
```

Martin's last example is obviously the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt=0
for number in range(0,1000,5):
        cnt+=number


cnt2=0
for number2 in range(0,1000,3):
        cnt2+=number2


cnt3=0
for number3 in range(0,1000,15):
        cnt3+=number3


print(cnt2+cnt-cnt3)
```

alas I've been studying for 1 week coding, sorry for the bad code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the multiples of 15 only once. I also ran into this error. I personally summed both arrays up before subtracting all multiples of 15 so they only get counted once, but you can also filter them out while getting the multiples of 5.

Here is my method in pseudo-code:

```
For each multiple of 3 below 1000:
    Add it to the result
For each multiple of 5 below 1000:
    Add it to the result
For each multiple of 15 below 1000:
    Subtract it from the result # To account for the multiples of 15 being added twice
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been a while back but hopefully by now you can reformulate your code into a convenient 1-liner such as:

```
result = sum([x for x in range(1000) if (x%3==0 or x%5==0)]
```

Keep coding!

Comment: This is actually worse than the `sum(x for x in range(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)` solution already given in my answer as you create a list first. It also is missing a closing `)`.

Comment: You also completely fail to address the question stated by the OP: what is wrong with their attempt at a solution.